# MySQL Insert Trigger not working with If Then Conditional

Tags: mysql, if-statement, triggers, sql-insert

I have created the following trigger in mysql:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `some_trigger` AFTER INSERT ON db1.table
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

IF NEW.userid = 'certain_id' THEN

INSERT INTO db2.table
SET

value1 = NEW.value,
value2 = NEW.value;

END IF;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

The above statement works if I remove the if statement. Additionally no syntax errors are encountered when this trigger is added to the db. Any idea what is wrong with the if statement that is not allowing it to insert entries with value 'certain_id' in column userid when added to db1.table??

Comment: How does it fail? Syntax error, other error, unexpected results?

Comment: What is the datatype of `db1.table.userid`, and what is the *actual value* of your `'certain_id'` literal?

Comment: No errors at all, just does not insert the value. Trigger is added successfully to the db.

Userid is a VARCHAR(255) created via uuid in another table. I also tried setting a variable to the value defined by the id in that other table but it did not work so I removed it to narrow down the problem.

Comment: What is the *actual value* of your `'certain_id'` literal?

Comment: '4125b2a0-2e43-11e2-b4a4-0022681f4c37'

Comment: @eggyal @cphlewis Created another trigger using a different method and this did not work either: `DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER 'trigger_name' AFTER INSERT ON db1.table

  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  
  INSERT INTO db2.table (row1, row2, row3)
select value1, value2, value3 from db1.table 
 where row1 = NEW.row1
 and userid in (select id from db1.users where user_group = 'group1');

 END
 $$
 
 DELIMITER ; ` Same thing no syntax errors, trigger added fine to db, but does not move the necessary values to the other db.

Comment: @Matt: It works fine for me.  Does the user that is defining the trigger have permission to insert into `db2.table`?

Comment: @eggyal Really? Odd it is definitely not working on my end, and again my original statement works without the if conditional so it seems there are few other variables. Root user.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it should work..

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `some_trigger` AFTER INSERT ON `db1`.`table`
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

    IF (NEW.userid = 'certain_id') THEN

        INSERT INTO `db2`.`table` (value1, value2)
            VALUES (NEW.value1,NEW.value2);

    END IF;

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```